# Why can't I download all files at high speed when I can stream HD YouTube videos without buffering?

Tags: windows, video, internet, download, youtube

I recently got a new internet connection. When I am watching videos on YouTube, there is no buffering for 720p or 1080p videos. If I download these videos using YouTube Download Manager, I get a download speed of 1MB/s.

However, If I download anything else from any other sites, my download speed is almost always below 100KB/s. Why does this happen? I have tried using IDM as well. Nothing increases my download speed. What can be the reason for such high download speeds for YouTube videos but nothing else.

When I use some other internet connection, I get the same High speed everywhere.

I am using Window 10 if that matters. Let me know if I need to add more details, this is my first question.

Comment: What's your ISP? What's your connection's advertised speed?

Comment: Keep in mind, good speeds are not just your internet connection. The server you're downloading from also needs to have a fast upload connection. Most of the times, they're set to deliver pages fast, but actual downloads slow. This can be easily achieved by setting a bandwidth cap of say... 100kb/s. Test this by visiting lots of different sites, best if you know it should download fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely your ISP has a very good connection to YouTube or a local caching accelerator. This provides unusually good connectivity to YouTube.

Comment: So, I guess there is no way I can increase my download speed for other sites. :)

Comment: It's hard to be sure without additional information. See the questions I asked in my comments to your question.